# which has a greater volume - unit sphere or a tetrahedron with given vertices?

Tags: integration, volume

I know the volume of a unit sphere is $\frac{4\pi}{3}$ (using integration) but I don't really know how to evaluate the volume of a tetrahedron with vertices:
$$(0,1,1), (0,-1,1), (-\pi,0,-1), (\pi,0,-1)$$

what is the way to approach this?

I think I found an answer, but not sure about it:
I can divide the tetrahedron to two equal halves. One of them with vertices:
$$(-\pi,0,-1), (\pi,0,-1), (0,0,1), (0,1,1)$$

The area of one cross section of that tetrahedron (parallel to the xz plane) is $y^2\cdot 2\pi$ at height $y$.

Thus, the volume of he entire half is given by the following integral:
$$\int_{0}^{1}y^2\cdot 2\pi \cdot dy=2\pi\int_{0}^{1}y^2 \cdot dy=2\pi\cdot (\frac{1^3}{3}-\frac{0^3}{3})=\frac{2\pi}{3}$$

and because of that the volume of the tetrahedron is $\frac{4\pi}{3}$

is this correct?

Comment: There's a lot of good stuff here: [Tetrahedron: Volume](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetrahedron#Volume) including a formula for the volume in terms of the length of the tetrahedron's edges.

Comment: It looks correct to me. Integration seems overkill for the tetrahedron now that you've split it into two smaller tetrahedra. The volume of each half can easily be calculated with the standard formula $hA/3$ where $A$ is the area of the base and $h$ the height. Use the three points on the y=0 cutting plane as the triangular base.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis our current topic was integration and we didn't prove the volume formula for a tetrahedron yet (only for a sphere) so it should be fine. and I assume the derivation of that formula also uses integration anyways..